# Declarative Jenkins pipeline syntax for pylint or flake8

Tags: python, jenkins, pylint

Can somebody help me with the declarative syntax of the Violation plugin or Warnings next generation plugin for pylint

I'm using the below syntax. But its not generating any graph

```
sh 'python3 -m pylint --fail-under=4.5 <module> <module> --msg-template="{path}:{line}: [{msg_id}({symbol}), {obj}] {msg}" > pylint.log || echo "pylint exited with $?"'

echo "linting Success, Generating Report"

warningsParsers canComputeNew: false, canResolveRelativePaths: false, defaultEncoding: '', excludePattern: '', healthy: '', includePattern: '', messagesPattern: '', parserConfigurations: [[parserName: 'PyLint', pattern: '*']], unHealthy: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below syntax to solve the problem

```
sh 'python3 -m pylint --output-format=parseable --fail-under=<threshold value> module --msg-template="{path}:{line}: [{msg_id}({symbol}), {obj}] {msg}" | tee pylint.log || echo "pylint exited with $?"'
echo "linting Success, Generating Report"
recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, aggregatingResults: true, tool: pyLint(pattern: 'pylint.log')
```